# How to dynamically render 2 components in a single component using $A.createComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to dynamically render 2 components inside a single component (say `c:componentA and c:componentB`).

I know we can do this for 1 component using `$A.createComponent` where we push the newcomponent to "body" and specify `{v.body}` in outer component markup. But as I want to render two components at 2 different places/times, how to differentiate between these 2 using same `{v.body}` in same component?

Ex: I want to dynamically render UI:Button(1st component) and on click of these, want to render modal pop(2nd compo) up dynamically. And I want both of these to be in same component markup.

Comment: What do you mean by 'differentiate'? You can add as many components you want in v.body.

Comment: @Santanu Halder I want to render 2 or more components at 2 or more different places in same component. Ex: I want to dynamically render UI:Buttons and on click of these, want to render modal pop up dynamically. And I want both of these to be in same component markup.

Comment: You can make use of aura:if and put your conditional component inside it. Make the condition true on button click.

Comment: I did try that but was not sure...it rendered the same component twice...but let me re-check this same approach again. Also, how efficient and advisable would it be to create an event on click of button and then render the modal pop up in parent component?

Comment: Sure. Re-try that approach. If doesn't work, post whatever you have done in the question, it will help us to understand better. And regarding your 2nd question, it pretty common to do that. Events are there do this.

Comment: As Santanu pointed out,  @Rangya add the code you have tried so far, so that we can help out.

Answer (score 1):

Declare two attributes in the component. For example, attribute1 and attribute2. You can create components dynamically and push the components to the new attributes. Remember to put {!v.attribute1} and {!v.attribute2} in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Declare two variables in the component with the below markup

```
<aura:attribute name="var1" type="Aura.Component[]" />
<aura:attribute name="var2" type="Aura.Component[]" />
```

In the component markup, based on the location you wish to embed the dynamic component place the markups {!v.var1} and {!v.var2}.

On the controller side, you can utilize the same logic as v.body

```
var containerLocation = component.get("v.var1");
containerLocation.push(newComponent);
component.set("v.var1", containerLocation);
```

Hope this helps.